# Create DX scratch org with caching disabled

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, scratch-org, caching

One of the most useful tips I've come across when developing lightning components in Salesforce is to [disable caching](http://www.desynit.com/dev-zone/salesforce-development/disable-browser-caching-for-lightning-components/), as otherwise Salesforce tends to aggressively cache components which makes development a nightmare.

However, now I'm using DX I'm having to do this manually in every scratch org I create, which is a real pain. Is there an option to do this automatically, either via a DX command org via the scratch org JSON definition file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can disable caching in scratch org by specifying **S1EncryptedStoragePref2** as disabled org preferences in your scratch org definition file.

```
{
    "orgName": "DevOrg",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled"],
        "disabled": ["S1EncryptedStoragePref2"]
    }
}
```

Thanks René Winkelmeye for this hint: https://twitter.com/muenzpraeger/status/961826088954486791

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much! I saw the `orgPreferences` tag was there, but couldn't find any list of what to send it... I've now found this page (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_orgpreferencesettings.htm), but unfortunately it doesn't say what all those options do, and not all are obvious!

Answer (score 3):

In the new scratch def format, here's the correct syntax:

```
{
    "orgName": "DevOrg",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings" : {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false,
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

....or this:

```
{
    "orgName": "DevOrg",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        },
    }
}
```