# What does each OrgPreferenceSetting do?

Tags: configuration, salesforcedx, scratch-org

Salesforce maintains a list of `OrgPreferenceSettings`, which allow scratch orgs to be spun up with [certain settings enabled or disabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_orgpreferencesettings.htm).

The full list from the above URL is, at the time of writing, as follows:

- AnalyticsSharingEnable (available in version 40.0 and later)
- AsyncSaveEnabled (available in version 40.0 and later)
- ChatterEnabled
- EnhancedEmailEnabled
- EventLogWaveIntegEnabled
- LoginForensicsEnabled
- NetworksEnabled (available in version 40.0 and later)
- NotesReservedPref01
- OfflineDraftsEnabled
- PathAssistantsEnabled
- S1DesktopEnabled
- S1EncryptedStoragePref2
- S1OfflinePref
- ScratchOrgManagementPref (available in version 41.0 and later)
- SendThroughGmailPref
- SocialProfilesEnable
- Translation (available in version 40.0 and later)
- VoiceEnabled

Some of these are obvious from the name - `ChatterEnabled` for instance enables or disables Chatter in the org. However, as can be seen from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207466/create-dx-scratch-org-with-caching-disabled), not all of these are obvious at all, but I've yet to find any official documentation on these org preferences or their functionality.

Is there a documented list of what each of these org preferences actually does, or is it just guesswork from the name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are those I could find:

- `AnalyticsSharingEnable` (available in version 40.0 and later)

  - <s>[Turn On Enhanced Folder Sharing for Reports and Dashboards](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=analytics_sharing_enable.htm&type=5)
    (?)</s>
  - [Use Your Salesforce Sharing Settings in Wave](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_edd_integrate_data_sharing_inheritance.htm)
- `AsyncSaveEnabled` (available in version 40.0 and later)

  - [Enabling Asynchronous API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214395&language=en_US&type=1)
- `ChatterEnabled`

  - [Chatter Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_enable.htm&type=5)
- `EnhancedEmailEnabled`

  - [Considerations for Setting Up Enhanced Email](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/emailadmin_enhanced_email_considerations.htm)
- `EventLogWaveIntegEnabled`

  - [Event Monitoring Wave App (GA)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_monitoring_wave.htm)
- `LoginForensicsEnabled`

  - [Monitor Login Activity with Login Forensics](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=event_monitoring_faq.htm&type=5)
- `NetworksEnabled` (available in version 40.0 and later)

  - [Enable Salesforce Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=5) (?)
- `NotesReservedPref01`

  - [Want to create a scratch org with Notes enabled via project-scratch-def.json](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XXEQA2)
- `OfflineDraftsEnabled`

  - [Enable Offline Access and Edit for the Salesforce App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/customize_sf1_offline_enable.htm)
- `PathAssistantsEnabled`

  - [Sales Path: Help Reps Follow Your Company’s Sales Processes in Lightning Experience](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_sales_sales_path_sfx.htm)
- `S1DesktopEnabled`

  - [Install and Customize Salesforce Desktop](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_desktop_install.htm&type=5)
- `S1EncryptedStoragePref2`

  - [Create DX scratch org with caching disabled](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207466/create-dx-scratch-org-with-caching-disabled)
- `S1OfflinePref`

  - [Enable Offline Access and Edit for the Salesforce App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_sf1_offline_enable.htm&type=5)
- `ScratchOrgManagementPref` (available in version 41.0 and later)

  - [Enable Dev Hub in Your Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm) (?)
- `SendThroughGmailPref`

  - [Send Email from Salesforce with Gmail™ or Office 365™](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_enable_send_through_external.htm&type=5)
- `SocialProfilesEnable`

  - [Set Up Social Accounts, Contacts, and Leads](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_networks_enable.htm&type=5)
- `Translation` (available in version 40.0 and later)

  - [Support Users in Multiple Languages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_overview.htm&type=5)
- `VoiceEnabled`

  - [Enable Lightning Dialer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=voice_impl_enable.htm&type=5) (?)

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much! From my other question, it seems that `S1EncryptedStoragePref2` is the (badly named) setting to turn off caching for lightning components, which makes development a whole lot easier. Not sure if it has any other side effects, though.

Answer (score 9):

An up-to date way of matching the `OrgPreferenceSettings` [list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) is using the [Settings metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm).

Using [heroku/force](https://github.com/heroku/force) CLI that would be:

```
force fetch -t Settings
```

Now you can search in the different settings metadata files for your org's preferences.

[image]

For example:

`Accounts.settings` contains the `enableAccountTeams` tag that would be translated `IsAccountTeamsEnabled` in the scratch-org definition file.

I'd put a bounty on an automatic translation tool if I could.