# Scratch orgs and Critical Updates

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, critical-update

I notice that all the scratch orgs I've been creating starting in Spring '18 open up with a reminder to **Enable the New URL Format for Lightning Experience and the Salesforce Mobile App**. Another update that could have an impact on our code is **Remove Instance Names From URLs for Visualforce, Community Builder, Site.com Studio, and Content Files**. Is there any way to programmatically flip on these updates from the SFDX command line after creating a scratch org?

*EDIT: It was suggested this is a duplicate of another question, however that one covered only features, not Critical Updates.*

Comment: +1, this would be incredibly useful but I've [yet to see an OrgPreferenceSetting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208172/what-does-each-orgpreferencesetting-do) that looks like it can do this.

Comment: It's come up because I'm working on a managed package that may need to do things that depend on URLs (e.g. `window.postMessage` from VF to Lightning, or a Remote Site Setting). Hence it would be nice to test in scratch orgs that both do and don't have the new settings enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does each OrgPreferenceSetting do?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208172/what-does-each-orgpreferencesetting-do)

Comment: Nope. That link does not address Critical Updates.

Comment: @PaulSweatte Please be careful when you initiate duplicate flags that the proposed duplicate is a true duplicate and provides a clear answer that addresses this question.

Comment: Is there a way to remove a duplicate flag?