# How to query if salesforce org has lightning enabled?

Tags: apex

[image]
I want to know if it is possible to use apex to query if the org has lightning turn on or turn off.
I try `SELECT s1DesktopEnabled FROM OrganizationSettingsDetail` but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

For the current running user you can use [UserInfo.getUiTheme()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getUiTheme) and [UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getUiThemeDisplayed).

You can also check [User.UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm). If that was false for all users then no users have it enabled by default.

You can access S1DesktopEnabled with via OrganizationSettingsDetail with the **Tooling API**. However, [I'm not sure that this setting has any relation to Lightning UI being enabled for the current org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/208184/102).

```
Select Id,SettingValue from OrganizationSettingsDetail where SettingName = 'S1DesktopEnabled'
```

---

Query to REST version of the Tooling API from Apex:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();  
req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()
   + '/services/data/v44.0/tooling/query/?q=' + 'Select+Id,SettingValue+from+OrganizationSettingsDetail+where+SettingName+=+\'S1DesktopEnabled\'');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

You will need to parse the "SettingValue" out of the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel,  
`UserInfo.getUiTheme() and UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() and User.UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred` are useful and I have been using them. 
Re. `Select Id,SettingValue from OrganizationSettingsDetail where SettingName = 'S1DesktopEnabled'` If we can use apex is the best solution.